# Is there a way to trigger a video using timer?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to build an app in which I want to trigger a video using timer, i.e. similar to alarm instead of alarm pop-up(with snooze & dismiss option) with music, i want my app to open the video page.

Please suggest me how to proceed.

Comment: Do you mean start the app (and play the video) at a certain time? Or start the video after a certain amount of time while using the app?

Comment: both.. but my primary focus is on to start video at a particular time selected by user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have an application start at a specific time. Apps can only be started in direct response to a user interaction.

There should be no problem in calling play on a mediaelement when a time (countdown) fires (expires). What specific problems have you had.